# kubectl cannot detect localhost:8080 with minikube locally

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I am trying to run the tutorial at https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/kubernetes-basics/create-cluster/cluster-interactive/ locally on by ubuntu 18 machine.

```
$ minikube start
      minikube v1.0.1 on linux (amd64)
      Downloading Kubernetes v1.14.1 images in the background ...
      Creating kvm2 VM (CPUs=2, Memory=2048MB, Disk=20000MB) ...
      "minikube" IP address is 192.168.39.247
      Configuring Docker as the container runtime ...
      Version of container runtime is 18.06.3-ce
    ⌛  Waiting for image downloads to complete ...
    ✨  Preparing Kubernetes environment ...
      Downloading kubeadm v1.14.1
      Downloading kubelet v1.14.1
      Pulling images required by Kubernetes v1.14.1 ...
      Launching Kubernetes v1.14.1 using kubeadm ... 
    ⌛  Waiting for pods: apiserver proxy etcd scheduler controller dns
      Configuring cluster permissions ...
      Verifying component health .....
      kubectl is now configured to use "minikube"
      Done! Thank you for using minikube!
```

So far, so good.
Next, I try to run

```
$ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"14", GitVersion:"v1.14.1", GitCommit:"b7394102d6ef778017f2ca4046abbaa23b88c290", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-04-08T17:11:31Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.1", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

Similar response for

```
$ kubectl cluster-info

To further debug and diagnose cluster problems, use 'kubectl cluster-info dump'.
The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

As also,

```
$ kubectl get nodes
The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

Ok so I was able to find the answer myself.

~/.kube/config was present before so I removed it first.

Next, when I ran the commands again, a config file was created again and that mentions the port as 8443.

So, need to make sure there is no old ~/.kube/config file present before starting minikube.